# adding user in roster list isn't working

Tags: android, xmpp

I am creating an simple one to one chat app, I've done with the message send and receive. Now I am trying to show the status of the user to another(contacts) like "online/offline" etc. For that I have to use Presence and Roster.But I don't know where and how to use that, I mean the complete flow of subscription request and accept and after the subscription, the status of the users i.e. Online/Offline etc.

Comment: did you try with?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to send and accept contact request

From **Open-fire** you can also do it from **back-end**

Steps :
First click on  Users/Groups  >> click on "UserName" >> click on roster >>  add roster

Here i attach screen of steps

- click on add new item

[image: click on add new item]

- add roster
  [image: add roster]
- edit roster and select subscription both
  [image: edit roster and select subscription both]

then after you will get roster list using this code

```
ArrayList<RosterEntry> rosterLists = new ArrayList<>();

 public List<RosterEntry> getFriendsList() throws SmackException.NotLoggedInException, InterruptedException, SmackException.NotConnectedException {
    rosterLists = new ArrayList<>();
    roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(Config.conn1);//connection object of AbstractXMPPConnection
    if (!roster.isLoaded()) {
        roster.reloadAndWait();
        Log.e("Roster :", "Reload and wait");
    }

    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    Log.e("Size of Roster :", entries.size() + "");

    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
        rosterLists.add(entry);
        Log.d("Buddies", "Here: " + entry.toString());
        Log.d("Buddies", "User: " + entry.getUser());//get userinfo
        Log.d("Buddies", "User Name:" + entry.getName());//get username
        Log.d("Buddies", "User Status: " + entry.getStatus());//get status of user
    }
    listAdapter = new FriendUserListAdapter(UserListActivity.this, rosterLists);
    user_list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    return rosterLists;
}
```

**what is the difference between subscription type both and from???**
When any user add bot has his/her contact, then in the end of whole process, subscription status of ofRoster(openfire) table is set to ‘from’. The desired result of this process is ‘both’

Comment: I have created two users in Openfire ,and as I tried users to add in roster, I can see the roster list in openfire for both users. but there's one confusion that subscription type is from in my case. Both user subscribed programmatically. So what is the difference between subscription type both and from???

Comment: When any user add bot has his/her contact, then in the end of whole process, subscription status of ofRoster(openfire) table is set to ‘from’.

The desired result of this process is ‘both’.

Comment: refer this -https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/subscription/readme.html

Comment: hope my ans will helpfull can you please do upvote and right tick?

Comment: where you want to get roster list it will return in list of users

Comment: ok, and how to find which user is online/offline etc.. . . I know for that I hv to use presence, but how

Comment: please edit your question i will post that ans, thank you

Comment: refer this ans -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367920/how-to-set-and-get-presence-in-xmpp-android

Comment: ok adil, I just did up vote to your answer, let me try this once only then I'll check this answer right. Hope u get me.thnku

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164607/discussion-between-adilhusen-and-nirmal-prajapat).