# How to add a search service for UserSearchManager in smack XMPP server?

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, smack

> ***Environment:***
>
> - Ejabberd Version : 16.04
> - Smack-android-4.1.0

I'm trying to create a chat application which has a feature to search the available users by name, age etc. However, when I use the below code it says, the server doesn't have any search services in the server.

```
public void serachServiceList() {

    try {
        UserSearchManager searchManager = new UserSearchManager(connection);
        List<String> services = searchManager.getSearchServices();

        if (services == null || services.size() < 1) {
            System.out.println("No services");
        } else {
            for (String service : services) {
                Log.e("SERVICE", service);
            }

        }
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException | XMPPException.XMPPErrorException | SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Aren't there any default search service in XMPP server? Do I have to install a search service separately? I searched but I could not find any search plugins for smack.
Would be glad to hear your solutions/ideas on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also develop same functionality but i use VCard to serach user  instead of SearchManager.

First of all need to add [all contact in roster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581009/adding-user-in-roster-list-isnt-working/48582474?noredirect=1#comment84279673_48582474) and using vcard you can get or set user avatar,get set user presence ,store user status like whatsapp etc,**search user using JID** etc

Here is my code search user from Vcard

**Search user ():**

```
public UserProfile search(String jid) throws SmackInvocationException {


    if (vCardHelper == null) {
        return null;
    }

    VCard vCard = vCardHelper.loadVCard(jid);
    String nickname = vCard.getNickName();

    return nickname == null ? null : new UserProfile(jid, vCard);
}
```

> UserProfile  is a model class which contains below values with garter setter

```
private String nickname;
private String jid;
private String status;
private byte[] avatar;
```

**getNickName():**

```
public String getNickname(String jid) throws SmackInvocationException {
        VCard vCard = vCardHelper.loadVCard(jid);

        return vCard.getNickName();
    }
```

**loadVCard():**

```
public VCard loadVCard(String jid) throws SmackInvocationException {
    VCard vCard = new VCard();
    try {
        vCard.load(con, jid);

        return vCard;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SmackInvocationException(e);
    }
}
```

Below code for get list of search user from server

> -here i saw a simple example here i create `AsyncTask` this
>   task put in `doInBackground`

```
try {
    UserProfile user = SmackHelper.getInstance(context).search(username);
    if (user != null) {
        if (user.getUserName().equals(PreferenceUtils.getUser(context))) {
            user.setType(UserProfile.TYPE_MYSELF);
        } else {
            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactTable.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactTable._ID},
                    ContactTable.COLUMN_NAME_JID + " = ?", new String[] {user.getJid()}, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                user.setType(UserProfile.TYPE_CONTACT);
            } else {
                user.setType(UserProfile.TYPE_NOT_CONTACT);
            }
        }
    }

    return Response.success(user);
} catch(SmackInvocationException e) {
     Log.e(String.format("search user error %s", e.toString()), e);

    return Response.error(e);
}
```